# Django RedirectView "CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, redirect, django-1.6

I am having a CSRF verification issue, even though I am using csrf_exempt decorator (via a helper mixin).

Here's my code:

```
class CSRFExemptMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CSRFExemptMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class IndexRedirectView(RedirectView, CSRFExemptMixin):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.visit_count >= 5:
            return reverse('gift-shop')
        if len(BaseGiftableInstance.objects.filter(giving_user=self.request.user)) > 0:
            # has won something
            return reverse('gift-shop')
        return reverse('spinner')
```

This is a Facebook canvas app.

Comment: The inheritance order matters, I'd try `class IndexRedirectView(CSRFExemptMixin, RedirectView)`

Comment: Thanks. Now the CSRF verification issue does not occur. But now I get a blank screen. The redirection doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm. I think I found the issue. It has something to do with a redirection from "https://" URL to "http://" URL.

Comment: Yes. Now I need to find a way to force Django to use https URLs. The problem is that I am using Cloud9. There I use the usual ./manage.py runserver instead of runsslserver which makes reverse function return "http://" URLs. But Cloud9 actually serves the pages via HTTPS.

Comment: That's a different question and, in fact, I'm afraid I'm unable to help you with it... Anyway, if my tip worked I'll post it as an answer so that you can accept it. I suggest you to create a new post with this new question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the inheritance order matters, you should replace

```
class IndexRedirectView(RedirectView, CSRFExemptMixin)
```

with

```
class IndexRedirectView(CSRFExemptMixin, RedirectView)
```

In the first case, the `IndexRedirectView`'s `dispatch()` method calls the `RedirectView`'s one, which does not have the `csrf_exempt` decorator, and that causes the CSRF verification to fail.